# Reducing array of objects with quantity

Tags: javascript

This code below comes from an API request:

```
const cleanData = [
            {
                company: "Company1",
                results: [
                    {
                        expirationDate: "2024-04-26T00:46:05Z",
                        licenseType: 'ENT'
                    },
                    {
                        expirationDate: "2024-04-26T00:46:05Z",
                        licenseType: 'ENT'
                    },
                    {
                        expirationDate: "2024-04-26T00:46:05Z",
                        licenseType: 'ENT'
                    },
                    {
                        expirationDate: "2024-04-26T00:46:05Z",
                        licenseType: 'ENT'
                    },
                    {
                        expirationDate: "2024-04-26T00:46:05Z",
                        licenseType: "MX250-SEC"
                    },
                    {
                        expirationDate: "2024-04-26T00:46:05Z",
                        licenseType: "MX250-SEC"
                    },
                    {
                        expirationDate: "2021-11-28T13:03:34Z",
                        licenseType: "MX250-SEC"
                    },
                    {
                        expirationDate: "2021-11-28T13:03:34Z",
                        licenseType: "MS210-48LP"
                    },
                    {
                        expirationDate: "2021-11-28T13:03:34Z",
                        licenseType: "MS210-48LP"
                    },
                ]
            },
            {
                company: "Company2",
                results: [
                    {
                        expirationDate: "2021-11-28T13:03:34Z",
                        licenseType: "MX250-SEC"
                    },
                    {
                        expirationDate: "2021-11-28T13:03:34Z",
                        licenseType: "MX250-SEC"
                    },
                    {
                        expirationDate: "2021-11-28T13:03:34Z",
                        licenseType: "MX250-SEC"
                    },
                    {
                        expirationDate: "2021-11-28T13:03:34Z",
                        licenseType: 'ENT'
                    },
                    {
                        expirationDate: "2021-11-28T13:03:34Z",
                        licenseType: 'ENT'
                    },
                    {
                        expirationDate: "2024-04-26T00:46:05Z",
                        licenseType: 'ENT'
                    },
                    {
                        expirationDate: "2021-11-28T13:03:34Z",
                        licenseType: "MX250-SEC"
                    },
                    {
                        expirationDate: "2021-11-28T13:03:34Z",
                        licenseType: "MS210-48LP"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
```

My question is... How can I turn it into an Object of Arrays or (Array of Objects) that reduces according to multiple dates and multiple licenseType, for example:

```
results: {[
 company 1: {[
   {
     expirationDate: "2024-04-26T00:46:05Z",
     licenseType: 'ENT',
     quantity: 4
   },
   {
     expirationDate: "2024-04-26T00:46:05Z",
     licenseType: 'MX250-SEC',
     quantity: 2
   },
   {
     expirationDate: "2021-11-28T13:03:34Z",
     quantity: 1
     licenseType: "MS210-48LP"
   },
   {
     expirationDate: "2021-11-28T13:03:34Z",
     licenseType: 'MS210-48LP',
     quantity: 2
   },
 ]},
 company2: {[
   {
    expirationDate: "2021-11-28T13:03:34Z",
    quantity: 3
    licenseType: "MX250-SEC"
   },
   {
    expirationDate: "2021-11-28T13:03:34Z",
    quantity: 2
    licenseType: "ENT"
   },
   {
    expirationDate: "2024-04-26T00:46:05Z",
    quantity: 1
    licenseType: "ENT"
   },
   {
    expirationDate: "2021-11-28T13:03:34Z",
    quantity: 1
    licenseType: "MX250-SEC"
   },
   {
    expirationDate: "2021-11-28T13:03:34Z",
    quantity: 1
    licenseType: "MS210-48LP"
   },
 ]}
]}
```

It doenst need to be exactly this way, but I really would like to have the quantity according to dates and licenseType. Thanks!

Comment: `results: {[` won't work because there is no key for the array in the object...

Comment: The key is license type if you're confused on how to group them by.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a little bit of help from `Array.map` and `Array.reduce`. It's not clear how you want to handle `expirationDate` so I'm overwriting that value with whatever the current value is.

```js
const cleanData = [{
    company: "Company1",
    results: [{
        expirationDate: "2024-04-26T00:46:05Z",
        licenseType: 'ENT'
      },
      {
        expirationDate: "2024-04-26T00:46:05Z",
        licenseType: 'ENT'
      },
      {
        expirationDate: "2024-04-26T00:46:05Z",
        licenseType: 'ENT'
      },
      {
        expirationDate: "2024-04-26T00:46:05Z",
        licenseType: 'ENT'
      },
      {
        expirationDate: "2024-04-26T00:46:05Z",
        licenseType: "MX250-SEC"
      },
      {
        expirationDate: "2024-04-26T00:46:05Z",
        licenseType: "MX250-SEC"
      },
      {
        expirationDate: "2021-11-28T13:03:34Z",
        licenseType: "MX250-SEC"
      },
      {
        expirationDate: "2021-11-28T13:03:34Z",
        licenseType: "MS210-48LP"
      },
      {
        expirationDate: "2021-11-28T13:03:34Z",
        licenseType: "MS210-48LP"
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    company: "Company2",
    results: [{
        expirationDate: "2021-11-28T13:03:34Z",
        licenseType: "MX250-SEC"
      },
      {
        expirationDate: "2021-11-28T13:03:34Z",
        licenseType: "MX250-SEC"
      },
      {
        expirationDate: "2021-11-28T13:03:34Z",
        licenseType: "MX250-SEC"
      },
      {
        expirationDate: "2021-11-28T13:03:34Z",
        licenseType: 'ENT'
      },
      {
        expirationDate: "2021-11-28T13:03:34Z",
        licenseType: 'ENT'
      },
      {
        expirationDate: "2024-04-26T00:46:05Z",
        licenseType: 'ENT'
      },
      {
        expirationDate: "2021-11-28T13:03:34Z",
        licenseType: "MX250-SEC"
      },
      {
        expirationDate: "2021-11-28T13:03:34Z",
        licenseType: "MS210-48LP"
      }
    ]
  }
]

const res = cleanData.map( company => {
  return company.results.reduce( (acc, curr) => {
    const match = acc.results.find(r => r.licenseType === curr.licenseType);
    if (match) {
      match.quantity += 1;
    } else {
      acc.results.push({ expirationDate: curr.expirationDate, licenseType: curr.licenseType, quantity: 1 });
    }
    return acc;
  }, { company: company.company, results: [] });
});
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using reduce() first to get the companies into an object. Inside that you would use reduce to build up a "map/table" of lic/exp and get the counts. You would than gran the Object's values to get your array.

```js
const cleanData = [{
    company: "Company1",
    results: [{
        expirationDate: "2024-04-26T00:46:05Z",
        licenseType: 'ENT'
      },
      {
        expirationDate: "2024-04-26T00:46:05Z",
        licenseType: 'ENT'
      },
      {
        expirationDate: "2024-04-26T00:46:05Z",
        licenseType: 'ENT'
      },
      {
        expirationDate: "2024-04-26T00:46:05Z",
        licenseType: 'ENT'
      },
      {
        expirationDate: "2024-04-26T00:46:05Z",
        licenseType: "MX250-SEC"
      },
      {
        expirationDate: "2024-04-26T00:46:05Z",
        licenseType: "MX250-SEC"
      },
      {
        expirationDate: "2021-11-28T13:03:34Z",
        licenseType: "MX250-SEC"
      },
      {
        expirationDate: "2021-11-28T13:03:34Z",
        licenseType: "MS210-48LP"
      },
      {
        expirationDate: "2021-11-28T13:03:34Z",
        licenseType: "MS210-48LP"
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    company: "Company2",
    results: [{
        expirationDate: "2021-11-28T13:03:34Z",
        licenseType: "MX250-SEC"
      },
      {
        expirationDate: "2021-11-28T13:03:34Z",
        licenseType: "MX250-SEC"
      },
      {
        expirationDate: "2021-11-28T13:03:34Z",
        licenseType: "MX250-SEC"
      },
      {
        expirationDate: "2021-11-28T13:03:34Z",
        licenseType: 'ENT'
      },
      {
        expirationDate: "2021-11-28T13:03:34Z",
        licenseType: 'ENT'
      },
      {
        expirationDate: "2024-04-26T00:46:05Z",
        licenseType: 'ENT'
      },
      {
        expirationDate: "2021-11-28T13:03:34Z",
        licenseType: "MX250-SEC"
      },
      {
        expirationDate: "2021-11-28T13:03:34Z",
        licenseType: "MS210-48LP"
      }
    ]
  }
];

const companyQty = cleanData.reduce((obj, {
  company,
  results
}) => {
  obj[company] = Object.values(results.reduce((data, {
    licenseType,
    expirationDate
  }) => {
    // generate the key based on what is the group
    const key = licenseType + expirationDate;
    //have we seen it, if not create record
    if (!data[key]) data[key] = {
      licenseType,
      expirationDate,
      qty: 0
    };
    // update quantity
    data[key].qty++;
    return data;
  }, {}));
  return obj;
}, {});
```

Answer (score 1):

Vanilla javascript version, here we created a `hashtable` for a particular company containing data grouped by the combination of **expirationDate + licenseType** keys and then use `for-in` loop to fill the values from `hashtable` to particular company

```js
const cleanData = [
    {
        company: "Company1",
        results: [
            {
                expirationDate: "2024-04-26T00:46:05Z",
                licenseType: 'ENT'
            },
            {
                expirationDate: "2024-04-26T00:46:05Z",
                licenseType: 'ENT'
            },
            {
                expirationDate: "2024-04-26T00:46:05Z",
                licenseType: 'ENT'
            },
            {
                expirationDate: "2024-04-26T00:46:05Z",
                licenseType: 'ENT'
            },
            {
                expirationDate: "2024-04-26T00:46:05Z",
                licenseType: "MX250-SEC"
            },
            {
                expirationDate: "2024-04-26T00:46:05Z",
                licenseType: "MX250-SEC"
            },
            {
                expirationDate: "2021-11-28T13:03:34Z",
                licenseType: "MX250-SEC"
            },
            {
                expirationDate: "2021-11-28T13:03:34Z",
                licenseType: "MS210-48LP"
            },
            {
                expirationDate: "2021-11-28T13:03:34Z",
                licenseType: "MS210-48LP"
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        company: "Company2",
        results: [
            {
                expirationDate: "2021-11-28T13:03:34Z",
                licenseType: "MX250-SEC"
            },
            {
                expirationDate: "2021-11-28T13:03:34Z",
                licenseType: "MX250-SEC"
            },
            {
                expirationDate: "2021-11-28T13:03:34Z",
                licenseType: "MX250-SEC"
            },
            {
                expirationDate: "2021-11-28T13:03:34Z",
                licenseType: 'ENT'
            },
            {
                expirationDate: "2021-11-28T13:03:34Z",
                licenseType: 'ENT'
            },
            {
                expirationDate: "2024-04-26T00:46:05Z",
                licenseType: 'ENT'
            },
            {
                expirationDate: "2021-11-28T13:03:34Z",
                licenseType: "MX250-SEC"
            },
            {
                expirationDate: "2021-11-28T13:03:34Z",
                licenseType: "MS210-48LP"
            }
        ]
    }
];

let grouped_result = {};

for(let i=0; i<cleanData.length; i++){
    let results = cleanData[i].results;
    let results_hash = {};
    for(let j=0; j<results.length; j++){
        if(!results_hash[results[j].expirationDate + results[j].licenseType]){
            results_hash[results[j].expirationDate + results[j].licenseType] = {
                expirationDate: results[j].expirationDate,
                licenseType: results[j].licenseType,
                count: 1
            };
        }else{
            results_hash[results[j].expirationDate + results[j].licenseType].count++;
        }
    }
    grouped_result[cleanData[i].company] = [];
    for(const x in results_hash)
    grouped_result[cleanData[i].company].push(results_hash[x]);

}

console.log(grouped_result);
```

Answer (score 1):

This approach converts each `results` property into an object that looks like

```js
{
    "2021-11-28T13:03:34Z|MS210-48LP": {
        expirationDate: "2021-11-28T13:03:34Z",
        licenseType: "MS210-48LP",
        quantity: 2
    },
    "2021-11-28T13:03:34Z|MX250-SEC": {
        expirationDate: "2021-11-28T13:03:34Z",
        licenseType: "MX250-SEC",
        quantity: 1
    },
    // ...
}
```

then calls `Object.values` to get the final values.  This is wrapped in a function that converts the original array into an array of `key-value` array pairs using the above for the `value` and the company name as `key`, on which we call `Object.fromEntries` to get the requested format.

Here is an implementation:

```js
const compress = (cleanData) => 
  Object.fromEntries (cleanData .map (({company, results}) => [
    company, 
    Object .values (results .reduce (
      (a, o, _, __, key = o .expirationDate + '|' + o .licenseType) => ({
        ...a,
        [key]: {...a [key], ...o, quantity: ((a [key] || {}) .quantity || 0) + 1}
      }), 
      {}
    ))
  ]))

const cleanData = [{company: "Company1", results: [{expirationDate: "2024-04-26T00:46:05Z", licenseType: 'ENT'}, {expirationDate: "2024-04-26T00:46:05Z", licenseType: 'ENT'}, {expirationDate: "2024-04-26T00:46:05Z", licenseType: 'ENT'}, {expirationDate: "2024-04-26T00:46:05Z", licenseType: 'ENT'}, {expirationDate: "2024-04-26T00:46:05Z", licenseType: "MX250-SEC"}, {expirationDate: "2024-04-26T00:46:05Z", licenseType: "MX250-SEC"}, {expirationDate: "2021-11-28T13:03:34Z", licenseType: "MX250-SEC"}, {expirationDate: "2021-11-28T13:03:34Z", licenseType: "MS210-48LP"}, {expirationDate: "2021-11-28T13:03:34Z", licenseType: "MS210-48LP"}]}, {company: "Company2", results: [{expirationDate: "2021-11-28T13:03:34Z", licenseType: "MX250-SEC"}, {expirationDate: "2021-11-28T13:03:34Z", licenseType: "MX250-SEC"}, {expirationDate: "2021-11-28T13:03:34Z", licenseType: "MX250-SEC"}, {expirationDate: "2021-11-28T13:03:34Z", licenseType: 'ENT'}, {expirationDate: "2021-11-28T13:03:34Z", licenseType: 'ENT'}, {expirationDate: "2024-04-26T00:46:05Z", licenseType: 'ENT'}, {expirationDate: "2021-11-28T13:03:34Z", licenseType: "MX250-SEC"}, {expirationDate: "2021-11-28T13:03:34Z", licenseType: "MS210-48LP"}]}]

console .log (compress (cleanData))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {min-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

One additional feature: this keeps all properties of the the input objects, not just the two supplied (and the `quantity`).  If multiple records have the same property, it defaults to the last one.  This may or may not be useful.  If  you don't want it, you can replace `{...a [key], ...o, quantity: <...>}` with something like `{expirationDate: o.expirationData, licenseType: o.licenseType, quantity: <...>}`, or you can destructure them in place of the `o` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.values, Array.reduce` if only 2 keys on each object.

```js
const cleanData = [
  {
  company: "Company1",
  results: [
      {
          expirationDate: "2024-04-26T00:46:05Z",
          licenseType: 'ENT'
      },
      {
          expirationDate: "2024-04-26T00:46:05Z",
          licenseType: 'ENT'
      },
      {
          expirationDate: "2024-04-26T00:46:05Z",
          licenseType: 'ENT'
      },
      {
          expirationDate: "2024-04-26T00:46:05Z",
          licenseType: 'ENT'
      },
      {
          expirationDate: "2024-04-26T00:46:05Z",
          licenseType: "MX250-SEC"
      },
      {
          expirationDate: "2024-04-26T00:46:05Z",
          licenseType: "MX250-SEC"
      },
      {
          expirationDate: "2021-11-28T13:03:34Z",
          licenseType: "MX250-SEC"
      },
      {
          expirationDate: "2021-11-28T13:03:34Z",
          licenseType: "MS210-48LP"
      },
      {
          expirationDate: "2021-11-28T13:03:34Z",
          licenseType: "MS210-48LP"
      },
  ]
},
{
  company: "Company2",
  results: [
      {
          expirationDate: "2021-11-28T13:03:34Z",
          licenseType: "MX250-SEC"
      },
      {
          expirationDate: "2021-11-28T13:03:34Z",
          licenseType: "MX250-SEC"
      },
      {
          expirationDate: "2021-11-28T13:03:34Z",
          licenseType: "MX250-SEC"
      },
      {
          expirationDate: "2021-11-28T13:03:34Z",
          licenseType: 'ENT'
      },
      {
          expirationDate: "2021-11-28T13:03:34Z",
          licenseType: 'ENT'
      },
      {
          expirationDate: "2024-04-26T00:46:05Z",
          licenseType: 'ENT'
      },
      {
          expirationDate: "2021-11-28T13:03:34Z",
          licenseType: "MX250-SEC"
      },
      {
          expirationDate: "2021-11-28T13:03:34Z",
          licenseType: "MS210-48LP"
      }
  ]
}
];

const result = {};
cleanData.forEach((item) => {
  const itemValues = Object.values(item);
  const resultValue = itemValues[1].map(item => JSON.stringify(item)).reduce((json,quantity)=>({...json, [quantity]:(json[quantity] | 0) + 1}),{});
  result[itemValues[0]] = Object.entries(resultValue).map(item => {
    return {
      ...JSON.parse(item[0]),
      quantity: item[1]
    };
  });
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: I have updated my answer. Have missed quantity before.